# ¿Existe alguna forma moderna/actualizada de manejar los listeners en Java?

Tags: java, poo, java-swing

Soy un desarrollador junior de Java y estoy leyendo un libro de Java, este libro tiene una forma interesante de manejar acciones realizadas en GUI.  Para hacerlo utiliza varias clases internas en cada clase del GUI de Java, cada clase interna con su propio ActionListener y actionPerformed().  Luego vincula cada componente a su correspondiente clase interna de oyente y ... Voilà!

No se requiere ni siquiera un bloque "if" para que este mecanismo funcione.  Se trata puramente de buen diseño OO.  Te agrega algunas líneas adicionales de código, pero tal vez la relación pro/contra las justifique.  No sé.

Me gusta este enfoque, pero se siente un poco exagerado ...
Mi pregunta es, ¿hay algún enfoque nuevo/mejor para esto que deba conocer para manejar acciones y oyentes?

Comment: Estas en SO en español, traduce por favor o tu pregunta quedará cerrada

Comment: Jeje, lo siento, ahora lo traduzco

Comment: Listo, ya hice la traducción.

Comment: ¿Tu pregunta es entonces acerca de alternativas mejores y más modernas (en base a la opinión de alguien) para el patrón de diseño Observador en Java o en swing en particular?

Comment: Sí, sin lugar a dudas.

Comment: No necesariamente tiene que ser opinión, hay muchos autores que hacen libros de Java, tal vez algún autor escribió sobre esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

además de existir esa forma de manejar eventos existen dos mas:
la primera es con clases anónimas, se crea un nuevo objeto de el tipo de una interfaz oyente y luego en el mismo parámetro addXXXListener se sobrescribe el método listener, en este ejemplo cada vez que se presiona un botón se imprime "hola mundo" en consola:

```
public class EventosConClasesAnonimas extends JFrame{
EventosConClasesAnonimas(){
    JButton boton = new JButton("hola mundo");
    add(boton);
    setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
    setVisible(true);
    
    //esta es la parte importante en que se le agrega un ActionListener a un boton mediante una clase anonima
    boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("hola mundo");
        }
    });//atencion a como termina, con punto y coma ya que todo esto pasa dentro de los parametros de el metodo addActionListener
}
```

la otra forma es con lambdas, es muy parecido al anterior, es la mas moderna y la que es correcta aunque a mi me gusta mas la anterior, en esta con una simple sintaxis se le da un oyente al boton, lambdas es un tema extenso, este ejemplo hace lo mismo que el anterior pero con una lambda:

```
public class EventosConClasesAnonimas extends JFrame{
EventosConClasesAnonimas(){
    JButton boton = new JButton("hola mundo");
    add(boton);
    setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
    setVisible(true);

    //esta es la parte importante en que se le agrega un ActionListener a un boton mediante una lambda, ahora es solo una linea de codigo aunque con llaves se pueden agrgar todas las necesarias
    boton.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("hola mundo"));
}
```

Comment: di tu respuesta como la acertada porque considero que con lambdas es la manera mas moderna de resolver eso